# OBSOLETE - Duplicate Question Suggestion Boxes

Tags: script, questions, obsolete

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

*Duplicate Question Suggestion Boxes* is a UserScript for any Stack Exchange site that makes it extremely simple to check for duplicate questions for a post. In the **left side** it shows the duplicate question suggestions right under the title (the one you get when you ask the question) and in the **right side** it shows the related questions (moved from the sidebar).

When you click on a link, it opens the duplicate question close box. You can then easily click through the questions and view them all in the open duplicate question close box. This makes finding the right duplicate (if one exists) *blazingly fast* except for those weird cases where you need to visit the search...

#### License

[The Unicorn Software License](http://quickmediasolutions.com/unicorn)

#### Download

[UserScript](http://tom.hsc.be/meta/duplicate_question_suggestion_boxes.user.js) |
[Source](http://tom.hsc.be/meta/duplicate_question_suggestion_boxes.user.txt) | **Warning:** Names have been changed, remove the previous version first!

#### Platform

Any browser that can run / install UserScripts.

### Contact

I can be reached at `TomWij [at sign] live [dot character] com`.

### Code

JavaScript on the client side.

### Versions

- **1.1.1:** Small graphical fixes for Google Chrome, proper `clear:both` and removed element focus.
- **1.1:** Links now **open the duplicate question close box** and also get trimmed after 60 characters.

  Title was placed under the boxes instead of above it so it fits together with the question body.
- **1.0:** Script released to the public, two boxes that just have links to the question pages.

### Planned

- When there comes a future release, I will implement an update check for convenience.
- Interface improvements, there is some real estate stolen. How could this be fixed?
- *Do you have any ideas to be implemented?*

Comment: @GeorgeEdison what happened to it? Sounded so promising :)

Comment: @BrunoPereira: It's still there - I just made some changes to my website such that URLs ending in '/' are no longer accepted. I fixed the link in the post above.

Comment: hey @Tom, the script seems to be a bit broken off late, can you take a look? http://i.imgur.com/KxzrEZ3.png

Comment: It no longer works. Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

I've been a long time user of this script and really loved it.

The makeover is excellent, 1-click vote is pretty nice!

Some minor issues:

On Stack Overflow: Notice that the starting letter of the question("I") is still at the top

[image: Original]

---

[image: I stuck at top]

Seems to happen at cases where the question length exceeds certain limit

Example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830/not-showing-dialog-when-opening-file-in-acrobat-pro-using-applescript

But this is fine:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193684/acrobat-reader-causing-constant-changes-in-screen-resolution

Meta has the same cut-off problem

[image]

---

Some styling problems at Web Apps, Apple

[image]

[image]

Comment: This has been resolved now, apparently Google Chrome acted different but actually more correct.